# Most efficient way to print variable number of characters in Hack?

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I'm working on a Hack project and I've come across a situation where I need to print `$n` spaces. Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) echo " ";
```

I'm wondering whether `$n` calls to echo is the most efficient way to go about this? From a little bit of googling, I learned that generally, multiple calls to echo are faster than string concatenation and that Hack doesn't have a built in StringBuilder equivalent. Does my for loop achieve that maximum efficiency or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the proper tool https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using HackLang, you should use [`HSL` ( Hack standard library )](https://github.com/hhvm/hsl) instead of legacy php functions.

The best way to go around this is to use `Str\repeat` function ( similar behavior as `str_repeat` in PHP )

```
use namespace HH\Lib\Str;

echo Str\repeat(' ', $n);
```

> Note: make sure to use the same HSL version as HHVM
>
> if you are using HHVM 4 ( recommended ), do `composer require hhvm/hsl:^4`
>
> if you are using HHVM 3, do `hhvm $(which composer) require hhvm/hsl:^3`
>
> etc...